Flutter Local Notifications, Schedule not being shown
I am trying to use the flutter local notifications package and followed the documentation but having some issues on showcasing the notification on my flutter app.
I also tried to add this github code to my project as an alternative with no luck - https://github.com/vijayinyoutube/schedule_notification_app_demo/blob/master/lib/main.dart
[https://github.com/vijayinyoutube/schedule_notification_app_demo/blob/master/lib/home_page.dart]
homepage.dart -
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
runApp(MyApp(currentpage: 'All'));
  openMyDatabase();
}

onPressed: () {
            WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
            var reminder = NotificationsReminder();
            reminder.scheduleNotification();
}

notificationsreminder.dart -
class NotificationsReminder {
  late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  NotificationsReminder() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    var initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

    _createNotificationChannel();
    _requestIOSPermissions();
  }

  Future<void> _createNotificationChannel() async {
    var details = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'your_channel_id',
      'your_channel_name',
      description: 'your channel description',
      importance: Importance.max,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(details);

  Future<void> scheduleNotification() async {
    print('Scheduled notification for 5 seconds later');
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        0,
        'Scheduled Notification',
        'This notification was scheduled to appear after 5 seconds.',
        tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
        const NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              'your_channel_id', 'your_channel_name',
              channelDescription: 'your channel description',
              importance: Importance.max,
              priority: Priority.high,
              showWhen: false),
        ),
        androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
  }

}

AndroidManifest.xml -
   <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
    
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ActionBroadcastReceiver" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    


Here is my code which i used schedule Local notification. And it's worked with both android and ios.
Just you need to initialised in main.
main.dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // await setOptimalDisplayMode();
  LocalNotificationControllerManager.initializeNotifications();
  await LocalStorage.instance.init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

LocalNotificationControllerManager.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as db;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

class LocalNotificationControllerManager {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static Future<void> initializeNotifications() async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestNotificationsPermission();

    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('notification');
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotificationResponse,
    );
  }

  static void onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse(NotificationResponse response) {
    // Handle background notification response
  }

  static void onDidReceiveNotificationResponse(NotificationResponse response) {
    // Handle notification response when the app is in the foreground or background
  }

  static Future<void> scheduleNotificationAfter24Hours({
    required int notificationId,
    required String title,
    required String body,
  }) async {
    db.initializeTimeZones(); // Make sure to call this at the beginning of your app's initialization.

    final now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    final scheduledDate = now.add(const Duration(hours: 24));

    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your_channel_id',
      'your_channel_name',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      enableVibration: true,
    );

    NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = const NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      notificationId,
      title,
      body,
      scheduledDate,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dateAndTime,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }

  static Future<void> scheduleNotificationAt10({
    required int notificationId,
    required String title,
    required String body,
  }) async {
    db.initializeTimeZones(); // Make sure to call this at the beginning of your app's initialization.

    final now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    // final scheduledDate = now.add(const Duration(hours: 7));

    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your_channel_id',
      'your_channel_name',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      enableVibration: true,
    );

    NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = const NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );

    tz.TZDateTime nextInstanceOfTenAM() {
      final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
      tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, now.year, now.month, now.day, 10, 00, 00);
      if (scheduledDate.isBefore(now)) {
        scheduledDate = scheduledDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
      }
      return scheduledDate;
    }

    // Scheduling the notification at 10:00 AM every day
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        notificationId, title, body, nextInstanceOfTenAM(), platformChannelSpecifics,
        androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dateAndTime);
  }

  static Future<void> scheduleNotificationAfter5Seconds({
    required int notificationId,
    required String title,
    required String body,
  }) async {
    db.initializeTimeZones(); // Make sure to call this at the beginning of your app's initialization.

    final now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    final scheduledDate = now.add(const Duration(seconds: 5));

    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your_channel_id',
      'your_channel_name',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      enableVibration: true,
    );

    NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = const NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      notificationId,
      title,
      body,
      scheduledDate,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dateAndTime,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }

  static Future<void> scheduleNotificationTomorrow({
    required int notificationId,
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required TimeOfDay notificationTime,
  }) async {
    db.initializeTimeZones(); // Make sure to call this at the beginning of your app's initialization.
    final now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    // Todo :- original
    final tomorrow = now.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    // Todo :- test
    // final tomorrow = now.add(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    final scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime(
      tz.local,
      tomorrow.year,
      tomorrow.month,
      tomorrow.day,
      notificationTime.hour,
      notificationTime.minute,
    );

    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your_channel_id',
      'your_channel_name',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      enableVibration: true,
    );

    NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = const NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      notificationId,
      title,
      body,
      scheduledDate,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dateAndTime,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }

//dhruv
  static Future<void> scheduleNotificationByDateAndTime({
    required int notificationId,
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required DateTime scheduledDateTime,
  }) async {
    db.initializeTimeZones(); // Make sure to call this at the beginning of your app's initialization.

    final now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    final tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime.from(scheduledDateTime, tz.local);

    // If the scheduled date/time is in the past, add one day to the scheduled date
    final adjustedScheduledDate = scheduledDate.isBefore(now) ? scheduledDate.add(Duration(days: 1)) : scheduledDate;

    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your_channel_id',
      'your_channel_name',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      enableVibration: true,
    );

    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      notificationId,
      title,
      body,
      scheduledDate,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dateAndTime,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }

  static Future<void> cancelAllNotifications() async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  }

  static Future<void> cancelNotificationsWithId(int notificationId) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(notificationId);
  }
}

need to add below permission
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />

Add code in AndroidManifest.xml, Inside <application> tag

        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


tried to implement that to my code but still no luck unfortunately :(

check updated code please
